# How to hide some element with jquery by using some element value as a condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html:

```
<button id="hideToggle">show/hide</button>
<form id="item">
    <div>Item 1 <input name="item1" type="number"/></div>
    <div>Item 2 <input name="item2" type="number"/></div>
    <div>Item 3 <input name="item3" type="number"/></div>
</form>
```

How can I hide each `<div>` inside `<form>` on condition that, when the `<button>` is clicked, if the `<input>` value is greater than 0, then it wont hide, otherwise `<div>` will be hidden ?

How do I write the javascript and/or jquery needed for this?

Comment: well, maybe for value other than 0 or '' they will hide. something like that

Comment: What do you want to do if `value` is not a number (some text, for example)?

Comment: Once the input is hidden, how can you change the value?

Comment: press the button again

Comment: @user3333218 but the value will still be the same.... I really don't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: im not trying to change the value, i only want to hide div so i can recheck the input form. because the real form in consist of about 50 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#hideToggle").click(function(){
    $("#item").find("input").each(function(){
        if(this.value <= 0) {
           $(this).parent().toggle();
        }
    });
});

$("#showAll").click(function(){
   $("#item").children("div").show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mL5qP/1/)

Comment: Exactly what I was writing haha.

Comment: This doesn't show the unmatched hidden elements on the second click.

Comment: @undefined Well, from the OP logic, you cant *show* the input since the input itself is hidden. You can't change the value. I don't really understand what the OP is trying to do actually

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes, the logic seems to be _broken_.

Comment: Changed to `toggle`, so that button shows hidden elements on second click. Also made a fiddle.

Comment: i think i need one more button which "show all", seems complicated if only one button to do toggle

Comment: Updated answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click","#hideToggle",function(){
  $("#item input").each(function(){
    if(!(parseInt($(this).val()) > 0)){
        $(this).parent().hide();
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which also checks if value is a `Number`. All the descriptions are in comments:

```
//attach click listener to the button
$(document).on("click", "#hideToggle", function(){
    //get all input type="number", descendant to "#item"
    var inputs = $("#item").find("input[type='number']");

    //go over each input
    $.each(inputs, function(index, elem){
        //try to parse it's value as a number
        var number = parseInt($(elem).val());

        //if value is a number
        if(!isNaN(number)){
            var hideCondition =  number <= 0;

            if(hideCondition) {
                //hide the parent div
                $(elem).parent("div").hide();
            }
        } else {
         //do something if value is not a number 
        }
    });
});
```

## Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/92jsz/)